# GCloud VM instance unloaded Nvidia drivers after reboot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia

I've been working with a VM instance on GCP for a while now and I had to reboot it because I had issues logging in through SSH. I used the "Reset" option in the VM Instances manager on the GCP website and the Nvidia drivers seem to be down after that.

I tried running `nvidia-smi` and got the following:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I don't know how to set it back up or why did this happen in the first place. Because of this I haven't been able to get my Docker containers back up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PIT-1](https://issuetracker.google.com/71950957), [PIT-2](https://issuetracker.google.com/71958620) and noticed that there are some WA for Ubuntu, you can try those; otherwise its seems to me that the issue you are having at the moment is intended behavior.

These are the steps to successfully install the drivers on CentOS 7:

1. Run sudo yum -y update kernel
2. Run sudo yum -y update
3. Stop and Start the instance
4. Run sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers -y
5. Follow the documentation starting at step 3 [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-driver-manual).

If you run "nvidia-smi" after following the instructions and stopping and starting the instance, you will be able to see the proper output as mentioned in the doc.

Comment: The provided documentation is for creating a new instance, is it correct?

Comment: @Eduardo, you can reopen PIT's and can get update on your issue.